When I launch from Dashboard, my sidenav navigates correctly to other pages. But when I launch from Log-in>Dashboard, sidenav couldn't locate pages?
Exactly as the title. I'm working on my Dashboard which I have no problem with navigating to other pages (Home, Transfer, etc.) Now that after I've worked with the Log-in page, and launching it from App.js, I get to the Dashboard as expected, but from there, I get a blank page when I click on 'Transfer'...etc.
I am using Polaris in here btw.
Here is my App.js syntax:
function App() {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <Frame>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LogIn />} />
          <Route path="/dash" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </Frame>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;"
And my Dashboard"
export function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
       topbar={<TopBarExample />}
      <Frame
       
        navigation={<Sidebar />}
      >
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/dash" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/dash/budgetApp" element={<Budget />} />
          <Route path="/dash/transfer" element={<TransferMoney />} />
        </Routes>
      </Frame>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

I have tried "<Route path="/dash/*" element={} />" on App.js above, and Dashboard still won't render navigation links.
I'm so lost here, hope all these details help. Thanks so much!
